# Get user session ID

Tags: development, session, httpcontext

I have a problem with SharePoint session. Is there any way to retrieve Session ID or Transaction ID of an user in SharePoint by C#?

Comment: Did you try HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID

Comment: @Nam Nguyen, what do you want to use it for? aanchal method is correct

Comment: Don't forget that the session state is disabled by default in SharePoint, if that's your problem. Use this to enable if this is the case: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607857(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

explore this code chunk and see if it works for you -

```
HttpSessionState fooState = HttpContext.Current.Session;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(fooState.SessionID);
```